# highlight using custom extension in notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I have to work these javascript files which do not have the typical `.js` extension.  Let's call this extension `.ce1` (for custom extension 1)

Every time I open one of these files in notepad++, I don't get any code highlighting unless I manually tell it to highlight as java-script.

Is there a way to make notepad++ automatically recognize the `ce1` expansion as java-script, and highlight it as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the top menu, open Settings->Style Configurator.  Under the language list select Javascript, then add "ce1" to the "User ext." field.  This should be exactly what you want.